# GSCAM Error in ROS

Tags: roslaunch, gscam, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I have some questions about using gscam in ROS environment and i using NVIDIA Jetson TX2 board, gstreamer-1.0

first, i tried cmd

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/vodep0" ! "video/x-raw, width=1280, height=800, framerate=30/1 format=(string)UYVY ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! "video/x-raw(memory::NVMM), width=1280, height=800, framerate=30/1, format=(string)I420" ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink
```

it's very well.

but i tried `roslaunch gscam gscam`, i have some errors.

```
path\to\ros\catkin\src\gscam\src\gscam.cpp::167:bool gscam::GSCam::init_stream() assetion failed" (outpad)
```

so, i had modified v4l.launch file to correct pipeline.

and have too same error.

what can i do for next step?

Thank you advise for me. everyone!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281103/gscam-error-in-ros/) by [pacientes](https://answers.ros.org/users/33455/pacientes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can ask gstreamer to explain an error using GST_DEBUG environment variable:

```
# GST_DEBUG=4 roslaunch gscam gscam
```

I'm sure that problem is in incorrect gstreamer pipeline config. Could you post your .launch file here?

---

Originally posted by [x029ah](https://answers.ros.org/users/33553/x029ah/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0